# Rookie - Ruby: Run file in terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal

Very inexperienced Ruby student here.

I’m not sure how to write a Ruby program in Atom, save it then try to run it in the terminal (Mac OSX).

Could someone run me through the absolute basics, please?

Forgive my cluelessness!

Comment: Write your program then save it e.g. `filename.rb`. In your terminal, change directory to where your program is saved. Then type `ruby filename.rb` to run the file (replace `filename.rb` with the name of your file). If you make changes, you need to re-save before you run it again.

Comment: Thanks, Sagar. I’ll give this a go soon.

Comment: It's a "Mac", short for "Macintosh", not "MAC" which is an acronym that [means something else entirely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address).

Comment: If you're just getting started with Ruby and want an easier way to run code, some editors support running Ruby out of the box. If you prefer a full IDE, [RubyMine](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) has you covered. Atom can also do it if you take the time to configure it, and there's a multitude of add-ons that can help make it easier.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I noticed Atom has the ability to run it. I’m still getting my hear around the terminal and how it works, so wanted to work directly from it. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: There's a quick trick that allows you to easily run your ruby script from different locations than where the script is located. Open a Terminal.app window and type `ruby `--note the trailing space--but do ***not*** hit return yet. Locate your program in the Finder and drag & drop it onto the Terminal.app window, where it will be expanded out to the fully qualified path name.  Select the Terminal window again, add command-line arguments (if the script uses them), and then press the return key to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby programs generally use the '.rb' extension, so in order to run a ruby file that you've written, you need to save it somewhere with that extension first- eg. 'my-app.rb'.

It's a good idea when starting out to save it in a folder inside your "Home" directory (/Users/*your user name*/). You can find that in the mac "Finder" by clicking on the folder on the left hand list that's named "your username". In your terminal, your home directory is shortened to '~/' - and you can easily change directory into it with that shortcut:

```
cd ~
```

While I've been learning, I've stuck to a quick, short directory to store my files- '~/code/'. Anything will do, but it's much quicker to type 'cd ~/code/my-app.rb' than to type something long like 'cd ~/Documents/Programming/Ruby/my-app.rb' every time. So when you're deciding on where to save, think about how much you'll have to type in terminal! :)

Once you've saved your file, and used 'cd' to change into the directory you've saved it in, you use the command 'ruby' to run it.

```
ruby my-app.rb
```

That's about all there is to actually running your file! There's so much more to using the terminal, and writing code- but there's plenty of info out there on how to start.

I found [Chris Pine's "Learn To Program"](https://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/chap_00.html/) really simple and easy to follow. There are plenty of other resources out there, too! Try out [Try Ruby](http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0) to get going straight in your browser.

Comment: Thank you! Your advice to stick to short directory names will be invaluable, I’m sure. Much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! Also, pressing "Tab" can autocomplete your directory names. So, "cd co *TAB*" will autocomplete "code". Sometimes it won't work until you type two or three letters, but try to force yourself to use it until it becomes second nature.

Comment: Just wanted to update you and let you know I successfully ran my Ruby program! Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem Kevin. I'm glad to have helped! Also, if you mark my answer as Accepted, we both get reputation for it on stackoverflow ;) *shameless*

Comment: Done! Thanks again!